# FDF-files not opening properly

Tags: itext, fdf

We have created a servlet that provides a FDF file for our clients. The FDF file is created by iText and the output looks fine. Whenever we open the FDF either from the Servlet, or from a local file, AcrobatReader starts, asks if the PDF should be downloaded, we allow that and then we see the PDF - without the values we filled in the form.

One thing that seems strange is, that regardless of the Browser, we get prompted about what to do with the PDF file that Adobe has tried to load. Anything else that clicking "open" will result in a empty Acrobat viewer window. I suspect that Acrobat forgets what to do with the PDF - but I have run out of ideas. Anyone got an idea where to look further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now solved the problem:

If you have any FDF/XFDF file, the PDF it references has to come from the same server. If it doesn't - it won't work and just show the PDF as if it was opened standalone.